# How to disable/enable an actionItem without an actionView in NativeScript Angular?

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have an ActionItem:

```
<ActionItem #finishActionItem text="Finish" ios.position="right" android.position="actionBar" (tap)="handleFinish()"></ActionItem>
```

How do I disable/enable the actionItem? I know this is very easy to do natively, but can't seem to figure out how to do within NativeScript angular.

I've tried using actionView, but actionView only works with some type of view within the actionItem. I do not want a label within the actionItem because that requires me to have to style it myself.

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NativeScript doesn't support that, but still you can do it with a bit of native code.

Inject `Page` in constructor

```
import { Page } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page";

...

constructor(private page: Page) { }
```

To disable `finishActionItem` in your code,

```
if (this.page.actionBar.android) {
                const menu = this.page.actionBar.nativeView.getMenu();
                menu.findItem(this.finishActionItem.nativeElement._getItemId()).setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                const navigationItem = this.page.ios.navigationItem,
                    barButtonItems = this.finishActionItem.nativeElement.ios.position === "left" ? navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems : navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems;

                let barButtonItem;
                for (const item of barButtonItems) {
                    if (item.accessibilityLabel === this.finishActionItem.nativeElement.text) {
                        barButtonItem = item;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (barButtonItem) {
                    barButtonItem.enabled = false;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Comment: I had to change the ios portion to:

        const barButtonItem = this.page.ios.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem;

        if (barButtonItem) {
            barButtonItem.enabled = enabled;
        }

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue.  I'm using Nativescript/Angular and tried to implement the above solution however the code cannot find this.finishActionItem.  I see that it's the ID  (#finishActionItem) of the Action item, but I get the red squiggly and compile error.  Is there something in this solution that is not shown above?  

My ActionBar is in my app.component.html so that it automatically displays in all pages for convenience and to prevent redundant code.  But it shows on my landing page and I'm trying to hide some of the ActionItem nodes Only from the landing page.

Comment: Webpack build done!
Project successfully prepared (android)
Successfully transferred tns-java-classes.js on device emulator-5554.
Successfully transferred vendor.js on device emulator-5554.
Restarting application on device emulator-5554...
Successfully synced application org.nativescript.blankng on device emulator-5554.
JS: HMR: Hot Module Replacement Enabled. Waiting for signal.
JS: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getMenu' of undefined.
Looks like I may be missing a library for the: actionBar.nativeView object?
this.page.actionBar.nativeView.getMenu();

Comment: Forgot to add that I have the code in my ngOnInit() : void { ... } method and it's in the landing view component, not in the app.component.ts.  The answer above does not specify where to put the code.

Comment: Your native elements will not be ready at ngOnInit. It's recommended to use loaded events of View to ensure the native elements are ready.

Comment: @Manoj - Tried it with ngAfterViewInit() : void { } and a few others, still the same error.  I might need to resort to another method all together, spent almost the whole day on this one already.  Thanks for your support.

Comment: As I already mentioned, use the loaded event on your root view or page.